# How to optimize the algorithm in Python

Tags: python

I tried to write a function that will hide a sensitive data from logs. But I am thinking about the optimizations. For example about reduction a nested loops. There are two options how a logs can pass in the function. First is as string, the second is as object that have a `__dict__` where "args" located. For exaple in a log

```py
logger.debug(
            "%s Body: '%s'",
            self.id,
            self.body,
        )
```

args will contain a tuple of args: ("some id", "some body")

```py
def _hide_sensitive_data(record):
    to_hide = ["access_token", "password"]
    items = record.__dict__.get("args")
    record_list = list(items)
    try:
        for i, item in enumerate(record_list):
            for field in to_hide:
                if field in str(item):
                    try:
                        record_json = json.loads(item)
                        record_json[field] = "*****"
                        record_list[i] = record_json
                    except json.JSONDecodeError:
                        pattern = re.compile(r'(password=|access_token=)([^& ]+)')
                        record_list[i] = re.sub(pattern, r'\2*****', item)
        record.__dict__["args"] = tuple(record_list)
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

Can you give an advice how to optimize this code?

Comment: Should be asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: My advice is not to optimize at all. If you ever find your performance to be insufficient, analyze bottlenecks and fix them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! @Mr.Polywhirl, the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You could have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *is for* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.